# How to make double underscore display as two separate underscores in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I don't know how to make a double underscore, i.e. a dunder, display as two single underscores in Python in PyCharm.

I have disabled font ligatures in

```
Editor -> Font,

Editor -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme Font,

Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Font
```

For all three of these, I use Consolas.

Basically, I want to achieve something like this:

```
 _ _class_ _ (without the spaces, of course).
```

What I have right now is this:

`__class__`.

I was expecting this to be easy, but I can't seem to find a straightforward answer to my question online.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a theme called `predawn`. The format of its font shows dunder separated from each other like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this without installing a theme, though?

Comment: No idea other than this

Answer (score 0):

You can go into settings -> Editor -> Font, and turn off ligatures.

Ligatures enabled:

[image]

Ligatures disabled:

[image]